# Install Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS on Non-PAE Capable Hardware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso-image, home-server

I read all about the [netboot mini.iso file](http://www.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/non-pae/) and understand the process.

I am looking for a non-PAE Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS netboot mini ISO image to install on an IBM ThinkPad X40 (from the year 2004), not an Ubuntu Desktop ISO image. Where can I find the necessary image file?

According to [this tutorial](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-1204-on-non-pae.html), the mini ISO file does not contain the server kernel when I saw the provided screenshots. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The netboot mini ISO **does indeed include** Ubuntu Server and other servers such as OpenSSH, DNS LAMP, Mail, Print, etc. Thank you for reading.